# Windows 7, Volume icon, does not function when clicked

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

The Volume icon is visible, but every time i click it, nothing happens.I have tried to remove the icon and put it back, turn off all icons and restarted my computer multiple times. How do i fix it?

Comment: Try reinstalling your sound card driver. Also try running `sfc /scannow` from an admin command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Check if the service is set to start manually, if so right click and open *Properties* and set service to start automatically.
2. Open *Device Manager* and check if the audio drivers are correctly installed and they are not outdated, if you don't find the drivers simply go to the manufactures website and download and install it.
3. Diagnose and check your speakers for any hardware related issues.

*Note: If any hardware issue is found, check if your product is still under warranty, and if so it should cover hardware.*